# perl split delimiter from file line by line

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a text file named 'dataexample' with multiple line like this:

```
a|30|40
b|50|70
```

then I split the delimiter with this code:

```
open(FILE, 'dataexample') or die "File not exist";
while(<FILE>){
    my @record = split(/\|/, $_);
    print "$record[0]";
}
close FILE;
```

when I `print "$record[0]"` , this is what I got:

```
ab
```

what I expect :

```
a 30 40
```

so when I do `print "$record[0][0]"` I expect the output to be: a

Where I got it wrong?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop `while ( <FILE> ) { ... }` reads a single line at a time from the file handle and puts it into `$_`

`my @record = split(/\|/, $_)` splits that line on pipe characters `|`, so since the first line is `"a|30|40\n"`, `@record` will now be `'a', '30', "40\n"`. The newline read from the file remains, and you should use `chomp` to remove it if you don't want it there

So now `$record[0]` is `a`, which you print, and then go on to read the next line in the file, setting `@record` to `'b', '50', "70\n"` this time. Now `$record[0]` is `b`, which you also print, showing `ab` on the console

You've now reached the end of the file, so the `while` loop terminates

It sounds like you're expecting a two-dimensional array. You can do that by pushing each array onto a main array each time you read a record, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

open my $fh, '<', 'dataexample' or die qq{Unable to open "dataexample" for input: $!};

my @data;

while ( <$fh> ) {
    chomp;
    my @record = split /\|/;
    push @data, \@record;
}

print "@{$data[0]}\n";

print "$data[0][0]\n";
```

#### output

```
a 30 40
a
```

Or, more concisely, like this, which produces exactly the same result but may be a little advanced for you

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

open my $fh, '<', 'dataexample' or die qq{Unable to open "dataexample" for input: $!};

my @data = map { chomp; [ split /\|/ ] } <$fh>;

print "@{$data[0]}\n";

print "$data[0][0]\n";
```

Some points to know about your own code

- You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program you write. It's a measure that will uncover many simple mistakes that you may not otherwise notice
- You should use *lexical filehandles* together with the three-parameter form or `open`. And an `open` may fail for many other reasons that the file not existing, so you should include the built-in `$!` variable in your `die` string to say *why* it failed
- Don't forget to `chomp` each record read from a file unless you want to keep then trailing newline or it doesn't matter to you
- You will be able to write more concise code if you get used to using the *default variable* `$_`. For instance, the second parameter to `split` is `$_` by default, so `split(/\|/, $_)` may be written as just `split /\|/`

You can use [`Data::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) to display the contents of your variables, which will help you to debug your code. [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) is superior, but it isn't a core module so you will probably have to install it before you can use it in your code

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer @Borodin. And for the extra explanation. I really need to learn more.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use

```
print "$record[1]";
print "$record[2]";
```

As they are stored in consecutive index values.

or

If you want to print the entire thing you can just do

```
print "@record\n";
```

Comment: the output of $record[1] is 3050, it's not what I expect

Comment: yes add a new line at end 30 is from first record and 50 is from seocnd record

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the value at the first index in the array each time through the loop, and without the new line. So you get the first value from each line, right next to each other *on the same line*, thus `ab`.

Print the whole array, under quotes, with the new line.  with your program changed a bit

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'dataexample';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Error opening $file: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my @record = split(/\|/, $_);
    print "@record\n";
}
close $fh;
```

With the quotes the elements are printed with spaces added between them so you get

```
a 30 40
b 50 70
```

---

If you print without quotes the elements get printed without extra spaces, so
this

```
print @record, "\n";
```

over the whole loop prints

```
a3040
b5070
```

If you don't have the new line `"\n"` either, it is all printed on one line so this

```
print @record;
```

altogether prints

```
a3040b5070
```

---

As for `$record[0][0]`, this is not valid for the array you have. This would print from a two-dimensional array. Take, for example

```
my @data = ( [1.1, 2.2], [10, 20] );
```

This array `@data` has at its first index a reference to an array -- more precisely, an *anonymous array* `[1.1, 2.2]`.  Its second element is an anonymous array `[10, 20]`.  So `$data[0][0]` is: the first element of `@data` (so the first of the two anonymous arrays inside), and then the first element of that array, thus `1.1`. Likewise `$data[1][1]` is `20`. 
Thanks to [Sobrique](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2566198/sobrique) for the comment.

But you don't have this in your program.  When you split data into an array

```
while(<FILE>){
   my @record = split(/\|/, $_);
   # ...
}
```

it creates a new array named `@record` every time through the loop.  So `@record` is a normal array, not two-dimensional. For that the syntax `$record[0][0]` doesn't mean much.

Comment: `my @record = ( [0] ); print $record[0][0];` - it is valid. It's just only if you have a 2d array (which the OP doesn't, although I think that's the assumption)

Comment: @Sobrique  Heh, yes, I smelled something wrong :).  Thank you, will correct.

Comment: yeah what I means is make it like multidimensional array, but since I'm not good with english, my question is not clear enough, sorry.

Comment: @Shitprogrammers Ah, OK.  I'll add a little more explanation. But note that you just don't have such an array in your problem.  You read a line of text into the array, overwriting it every time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to create a 2d array, whereby each element contains all the pipe delimited items from each line of your input:

```
my @record;
while(<DATA>){
    chomp;
    my @split = split(/\|/);
    push @record, [@split];
}

print "@{$record[0]}\n";
```

---

```
a 30 40
```

Comment: Can do the above with `my @records = map { chomp; [split /\|/] } <DATA>;`  too

Comment: @Sobrique I'm scared of `map` though

Comment: I was. I'm not any more. It's misuse a lot, but it's really cool when you get to grips with it. (like `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

`record[0]` has the contents of column 1 - 'a' on the first iteration of the loop, 'b' on the second.  `record[1]` has column 2 and so on.  You put the print statement, `print "record[0]"` **in** the loop so you get 'a' printed in the first iteration and 'b' in the second.

To get what you wanted you need to replace you print statement with;

```
print join " ", @record, "\n";
```